# Working with arrays and variable length formal parameters. (java:38: error: '.class' expected)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, compiler-errors, variable-length-array

I am not finished working on this program, so I know there may be other mistakes. I am currently getting the '.class' expected error, and for some reason I can't see that mistake.
I am using jGrasp and this is a project for my Intro to Java class.

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Final_Project_Test_Process_With_Arrays
        //Final Project
        //Mean and Standard Deviation
        //13.04.27
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Allow for the user to input numbers
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers?");
        int amount = kb.nextInt();
        double[] nums = new double[amount];

        for (int count = 0; count < nums.length; count++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number " + (count + 1) + ": ");
            nums[count] = kb.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.print("The mean of ");
        for (int index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
            System.out.print(nums[index] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.printf("is " + "%.2f", calcMean(nums));
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print("The Standard Deviation of ");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < nums.length; counter++) {
            System.out.print(nums[counter] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print("is " + calcStandardDeviation(amount, mean,double...nums));
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static double calcMean(double[] nums) {
        double sum = 0;
        double mean = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
            sum = sum + nums[index];
        }

        if (nums.length != 0)
            mean = sum / nums.length;

        return mean;
    }

    public static double calcStandardDeviation(int amount, double mean, double... nums) {
        double squared = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double radicand = 0;
        for (double num : nums) {
            squared = pow((num - mean), 2);
            sum = sum + squared;
        }
        radicand = sum / amount;

        double standardDeviation = sqrt(radicand);

        return standardDeviation;
    }
}
```

I know there is a simple answer, and I have done searches to help, but being a beginner at this, it's taking me too long to apply answers to other similar posts to my own problem.

Error messages are as follows:

```
Final_Project_Test_Process_With_Arrays.java:38: error: '.class' expected
    System.out.print("is " + calcStandardDeviation(amount, mean, double ... nums)); 
                                               ^                             
Final_Project_Test_Process_With_Arrays.java:38: error: ')' expected
    System.out.print("is " + calcStandardDeviation(amount, mean, double ... nums)); 
                                                  ^                             
Final_Project_Test_Process_With_Arrays.java:38: error: ';' expected
    System.out.print("is " + calcStandardDeviation(amount, mean, double ... nums)); 
                                                    ^                               
Final_Project_Test_Process_With_Arrays.java:38: error: illegal start of expression
    System.out.print("is " + calcStandardDeviation(amount, mean, double ... nums)); 
                                                     ^                               4 errors
```

The ^ is always pointing to amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem that I can see is the way you are invoking the `calcStandardDeviation` method -

```
System.out.print("is " + calcStandardDeviation(amount, mean, double ... nums));
```

That actually should be -

```
System.out.print("is " + calcStandardDeviation(amount, mean, nums));
```

Also, you haven't declared the variable `mean` (that you are passing to the method).

Comment: aha! Thanks so much!! That fixes it! Now on to finish fixing the easier mistakes!

Comment: Finally finished the project! This error was the one thorn in my side.  Thanks again for your help!